# Flutter fl_chart - How can we avoid the overlap of the ordinate?

Tags: flutter, fl-chart

i have a chart and sometimes, the ordonate overlaps the min or/and the max value
[image]

Can this be avoided?

Thx

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid this by checking if the value is the same as the max or min Y value using the "meta" parameter in your "getTitlesWidget" function.

```
Widget getTitlesWidget(double value, TitleMeta meta) {
    if (value == meta.max) {
      return const Text('');
    } else if (value == meta.min) {
      return const Text('');
    }
    return Text('$value');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The meta parameter also has an `axisPosition` property you can check in the `getTitlesWidget` method:

```
leftTitles: AxisTitles(
                              sideTitles: SideTitles(
                                showTitles: true,
                                reservedSize: 42,
                                getTitlesWidget: (value, meta) {
                                  if (meta.axisPosition == 0) return Container();

                                  return Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
                                    child: Text(
                                      value.toStringAsFixed(0),
                                      style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black87),
                                    ),
                                  );
                                },
                              ),
                            ),
```